# Magento is not updating product prices on front end after VAT change

Tags: ce-1.9.1.0, tax-class, product-prices

From the 1st of June the VAT had been reduced from 24% to 9% on some products. We have changed all the prices in the backend, set the new VAT in the tax class and yet the prices are still calculated with 24% instead of 9%. In the backend they show up correctly.

The prices are added with the including tax, so for ex. something that has the total price of 10 the product price should be 9,17 and the VAT should be 0,83. This is how it's displayed in the backend, on the front end it's calculated as 8,06 and 1,94 for VAT.

I flushed the cache, reindexed everything a couple of time, but still no idea why it won't update.

Comment: can you see the correct price on View page? If you find the difference in price between view and list page  then its related to Index Issue.

Comment: I am not sure, but this can be helpful https://rsquaremage.wordpress.com/

Answer (score 1):

It was a simple problem of having a different value set in the store view and the default view...

Sorry to waste everybodys time and thanks for trying to help.